# php link not found error

Tags: php, html

I recently started getting this error on my site :

```
The requested URL /ï»¿ilanlar.php was not found on this server.
```

although the link is correct and I have set the path and everything correctly, the link I try to access is as follows :

```
http://domain.com/%EF%BB%BFilanlar.php?il=34&ilce=34.35&mah17050&path=2
```

here the surprising thing is, I have the link defined as:

```
<a href='http://domain.com/ilanlar.php?il=34&ilce=34.35&mah17050&path=2'>CLICKY</a>
```

but the `%EF%BB%BF` part is being added automatically on its own, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the file encoding to `UTF8`, delete the link and type it again.

Don't copy/paste it. Type it.

Comment: I alread have the meta tag added to the header of my site 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` is that what you were talking about?

Comment: No the file ecoding is different than content-type meta tag. Use your text editor (like Notpad++ or Sublime) or IDE to change the file encoding.

Comment: its already set to utf-8, double checked it via `console` on `sublime text 2`

Comment: Then delete the text and type it again.

Comment: I just had to make a new file and paste all codes on it then save with encoding utf-8 and it worked, kinda confused though on why its that way